# Set default value in PostgreSQL table column to a value from a query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to do the following

```
ALTER TABLE runs ADD COLUMN userId bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT (SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = 'admin@example.com');
```

but it keeps giving me syntax error. How could I do this guys?
Any help is highly appreciated. ;)

Comment: its wrong _you cannot use subquery in default expression_

Answer (score 35, accepted):

1. Create a function to get the `id` from the table `users` with `email` as an arg.

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION id_in_users(iemail varchar) 
   RETURNS int LANGUAGE SQL AS $$
      SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = email;
   $$;
   ```
2. And alter the table

   ```
   ALTER TABLE runs ADD COLUMN userId bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT     
   id_in_users('admin@example.com');
   ```

---

[**SQL FIDDLE(DEMO)**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fcc39/9)

Comment: +1 I was curious to see if this worked so I created a SQL Fiddle and gave it a try and it looks like it works ok. Feel free to include the fiddle in your answer. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fcc39/9

Comment: Thanks guys, you're the best. I am surprised at how fast I got the answer. Keep it up guys ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can't do that on `DEFAULT`. However you could use a trigger before insert checking if there is a `NULL` value.

You can check the [PostgreSQL Trigger Documentation here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html)